# Update component data when click on checkbox from other component in Angular 5

Tags: angular

I have two components: `FoodComponent` and `CategoryComponent`

in category component html:

```
<div *ngFor="let category of categoryItems">
    <mat-checkbox data-id="{{category.id}}" (change)="loadFoods(category.id)">{{category.title}} ({{category.foodCount}})</mat-checkbox>
</div>
```

and

```
loadFoods(catId) {
   // update data to foodcomponent, I don't know how
}
```

In food component:

```
<mat-card class="food-card" *ngFor="let food of foodItems">
  <mat-card-header>
    <!-- <div mat-card-avatar class="food-header-image"></div> -->
    <mat-card-title>{{food.title}}</mat-card-title>
    <mat-card-subtitle>&nbsp;</mat-card-subtitle>
  </mat-card-header>
  <img mat-card-image src="https://material.angular.io/assets/img/examples/shiba2.jpg" alt="Photo of a Shiba Inu">
  <mat-card-content>
    <div>
      {{food.description}}
    </div>
  </mat-card-content>
  <mat-card-actions>
    <button mat-raised-button color="primary" class="left">Add to cart</button>
    <button mat-raised-button color="warn" class="left">Add to favourite</button>

    <button mat-button class="right">{{food.price}} USD</button>
    <div class="clear"></div>
  </mat-card-actions>
</mat-card>
```

The `foodItems` is initialised in `FoodComponent`.

Both have separate service: FoodService and CategoryService which make http requests to an api.

How to send data from CategoryComponent (where change event exists) to FoodComponent and update that array `foodItems` ?

Answer (score 0):

So if those two components have parent-child relationship you can just use @Input() @Output() properties. So if the child component changes and you want to notify the parent just `.emit(newValue)` from an @Output().

If they don't have parent-child relationship you can simply create a singleton service and share the state with observables/subjects by pushing the new state and subscribing to get the latest change from another component. Here is some code that could help https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction

If you need some more help let us know, but probably would be best to share some more code of those services.

Live example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ga7qfp
I was having some issues import the Http client there, but sharing state should be very similar even when you get the data from http.

Comment: they don't have relationship , just send data

Comment: this is a great read https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-and-children-communicate-via-a-service it explains how to push data with a Subject and listen to the changes with Observable of that data

Comment: dont worry about the title parent-child of that section. it works even if the components don't have this relationship

Comment: i am creating a js fiddle to demonstrate in a simple example what i mean - even if the docs are very good for this topic

Comment: hi @SnakeEyes. did you manage to create a subject to send the data that changes and subscribe to get the changes ?

Comment: No, I did with route and activatedRoute